# why does 'far' contribute to near plain in frustum?

Tags: opengl

in openGL, i made a viewing frustum by using inverse matrix of
PxV
P is made from glPerspect and V is made from gluLookAt

At first,
I think that the 'far' factor of P doesn't affect to vertices in near plain of frustum, but it does affect.

Then I assume that it is just floating-point precision error, and so there are no 'far' factor in real formula.
I calculated it to prove my assumption, but I failed. I cannot remove terms which contain (near + far) / (2 * near * far) form.

I think that near plain of frustum must be independent from 'far' factor. I cannot understand this situation. Where did I make mistake?

Comment: In what way did you think near is independent of far? They are used to calculate Z-Depth and there is a fixed number of bins of Z-Depth. If they are several orders of magnitude different, and your objects are near each other, you can't distinguish between them any more in Z-depth.

Comment: OpenGL needs the depth of a fragment to be between -1 and 1; a classical perspective projection matrix will translate `near` to -1 and `far` to 1. However, infinite depth perspective projection matrices exists: see [GLM's implementation](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/88f4a5ed827c316b5f6179bc51193a874a3a96ee/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl#L343)

Comment: I got a vertex of near plain by multiplying inverse matrix with (-1, -1, 0)

Comment: I think near plain is independent of far since near plain is perpendicular from direction and distance from eye is 'near'

Comment: the following are my assumptions

Comment: 1. factor of gluLookAt and fovy and aspect define a pyramid

Comment: 2. We can get viewing frustum by cutting this pyramid by two plains

Comment: they are perpencular from direction of camera and distances from eye are 'near' and 'far'

Comment: The distance between near and far will determine how well the limited precision of your depth buffer works. Effectively they are independent, but you will hurt the resolving power of your depth buffer if you make the range too large, at which point depths start to alias.

Comment: @GimunEom: (-1, -1, 0) is _not_ on the near plane. (-1, -1, -1, 1) is. And don't forget the final division by w.

Comment: @derhass : thanks. if z = -1, it is independent